# IntelliJ + sbt -> no external dependencies

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am trying to set up IntelliJ IDEA with sbt for a Scala project. The external dependencies are specified in my `build.sbt` and also listed inside the IDE, as can be seen in the screenshot. However, I still get compiler errors that saying the respective symbol cannot be resolved. Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Contents of my `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val midas = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "test",
    mainClass in assembly := Some("core.Service"),
    assemblyJarName in assembly := "test.jar",
    test in assembly := {},
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.25",
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.5.13",
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % "2.5.13",
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-remote" % "2.5.13",
      "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "1.1.0",
      "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.9",
      "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.2.3",
      "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.9.0",
      "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3",
      "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-core" % "1.2.3",
      "com.mchange" % "c3p0" % "0.9.5.2",
      "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.10",
      "org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "2.0.1",
      "net.sourceforge.jtds" % "jtds" % "1.3.1"
    )
  )
```

Still the dependencies for both, `akka` and `joda-time` cannot be resolved inside the IDE. The `sbt compile` from the command line works fine however.

[image]

Comment: Trying to reproduce from this information works fine for me. Please create a ticket on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL with an example project that reproduces this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`joda-convert` does not include `org.joda.time.DateTime` - you need `"joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.9.4"` or so.

Once you have added this (and fixed your missing Akka import, maybe `"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.17"`), you need to refresh the sbt project.

I press Shift, Shift to bring up "Search Everywhere" and type "sbt". Choose `sbt` under Tool Windows, then click "Refresh all sbt projects" (blue reload icon) in the sbt window. I close this window because it is not usually useful.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The import for datetime is there. 3 items up from the selection.

Comment: Oh yeah. Did you try the refresh button to no avail?

Comment: Yup. Even tired to invalidate cache and restart the IDE :/